# php regex get postal address from html dom

Tags: php, regex

am trying to get postal code (91150) from this html :

```
<div>

<strong>Adresse de la commune : </strong><br>
HOTEL DE VILLE<br>91150&nbsp;ABBEVILLE-LA-RIVIERE&nbsp;
<p>Téléphone : <strong>01 64 95 67 37</strong><br>
Fax : <strong>01 69 58 80 17</strong></p>


<p>Localisation géographique : </p>
</div>
```

in php i did:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('`<strong>Adresse de la commune : </strong>([^[0-9]]*)<p>`', $page, $regs);
var_dump($regs);// returns empty
```

can someone help thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite certain that your postal code more consequtive digits than phone and fax number. Using this idea you can extract it

```
preg_match('#Adresse de la commune\D+(\d{3,})#s', $page, $regs);
```

Comment: can't i kepp `<strong>Adresse de la commune : </strong>` because i have i big html file that have lot of numbers

Answer (score 0):

I simplified it a bit. Would this work for you?

```
preg_match('/[^0-9]([0-9]{5})[^0-9]/', $page, $regs);
```

Comment: can't i kepp `<strong>Adresse de la commune : </strong>` because i have i big html file that have lot of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Dump it like this:

```
$postalcode = preg_match('`<strong>Adresse de la commune : </strong>([^[0-9]]*)<p>`', $page, &$regs);
var_dump($postalcode);
```

Comment: i said that i get an empty array

Comment: well you are dumping the $regs, that does not contain the result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the post code is always written as a word of 5 consecutive digits, the code below can extract it:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\b(\d{5})\b/", $page, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 91150
```

The `\b`-anchors force the post code to be a word of its own. This way 5 digits in a 6-digit phone number wont match, for example.

Comment: i think you mean `$matches[0];`

Comment: Either works in this case; index `0` will have the part of the input that was matched, while index `1` is the first matching group. Here I could remove the parenthesis and just use the index `0` but I'm just more used to using matching groups.

Answer (score 0):

With this one:

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5}(?![0-9])
```

You can match any group of 5 numbers. You can then add more restrictions based on your input string.
If there's always a non-breaking space afterwards you could use:

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5}(?:&nbsp;)
```

And as many other restrictions as you need to make your regex more accurate for your input.
I used .NET regex syntax, I hope that's not an inconvenience.